# How to create mock ups in GIMP using templates like PSD in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, mockup

I am almost novice to graphic design. I need to know whether there is any way to create mock-ups in GIMP, people generally create in Photoshop with PSD format. Is there any format like PSD in GIMP, which can be used to create mock-ups easily?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. GIMP's native file format is XCF. It's the format you should use to save your original work for future editability (whether it's being used as a template or not). It's a lossless format, and it preserves all layers, and editable text layers.

Although GIMP also supports PSD to some degree, you should use XCF for full compatibility with GIMP.  However, Photoshop doesn't support XCF files at all, so if you need to open it in Photoshop, then you would need to export the image as a PSD from GIMP.

**Edit** (suggested by Joonas)

Note that GIMP doesn't have any Smart Object functionality at present, so any template/mockup design created with GIMP will necessarily involve more manual work in order to use it, when compared to Photoshop mockups that use Smart Objects to automate placement/transforms of images.  There are future plans by GIMP's developers to implement something similar to Smart Object functionality, but it's still some way off, unfortunately.

So are there ways to work around this handicap?

There are certainly possibilities, such as keeping a group with original editable elements hidden, which could then be duplicated, edited, then flattened to create a single layer which could then be transformed to fit on a mock-up. Obviously, this will still involve manual operations, and it's less than ideal and not as convenient as Smart Objects, but it could still work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a very clear answer! But could please suggest how to great .xcf templates to create mock ups?

Comment: A mock-up (or template) is simply an image with editable layers. If you don't know anything about layers, then use google to look up tutorials on using layers in GIMP. Another great source of GIMP tutorials is on Youtube. To save an XCF in GIMP, click File > Save as.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will follow it insAllah.

Comment: @tuxtu, I'm surprised you selected this answer. PSD mockups typically use a [Smart Objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html) and what the end user does is they just [swap the SO contents with their own graphics](https://youtu.be/XTxA9OPLqHo). — I thought you would've wanted to know if you could do that in Gimp?

Comment: @Joonas You are right! I didn't understand that properly, before as I am very new in this field. Now I am hoping for better answer. Hope you can provide one. :)

Comment: @tuxtu, I'm not a Gimp user, but I do know it doesn't have anything similar to smart objects. AFAIK, it's not possible to do those types of mockups in Gimp. I found [this post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/GIMP/comments/7slo48/implementing_psd_mockup_using_gimp/) where someone mentioned [Photopea](http://www.photopea.com/). Maybe that would help you? It does support psd files and smart objects...

Comment: @Joonas GIMP has no Smart Objects or any equivalent, so that's why I didn't mention their use.  However, GIMP does have layers, and so you could easily swap out/replace a layer. Obviously you may need to do a perspective transform or scale an object to fit on a mock-up, so the steps to use a template will be more manual and less automated than templates in Photoshop.

Comment: @BillyKerr, well yea, that was my point. When he was asking about doing mockups in Gimp, it seemed to me the need was to be able to swap the graphics without having to really do any manual work. So when the answer is: "Gimp has a file format that is (somewhat) equivalent to psd" I feel it kinda misses the mark.

Comment: @Joonas well yes I realize that, but then GIMP isn't Photoshop. Although apparently the GIMP developers do have plans to introduce some kind of Smart Object functionality in the future.  It's mentioned in the devs [Roadmap](https://wiki.gimp.org/index.php/Roadmap) wiki page. However, it will need a complete GEGL port first. GIMP development can be rather slow, since it's more or less dependent on volunteer developers.

Comment: @BillyKerr, I think you should mention it in the answer then. Seems kinda pointless to me to answer "here's the way to do it" and leave out that you actually can't.

Comment: @Joonas I've done that now.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @BillyKerr, now I think it's as good as it can be.

Comment: Would it make sense to create these in Inkscape? I saw the tag, and I think it being a vector graphics editor could make this easier. Although I have no idea what 'smart objects' are. We have symbols :)

Comment: Isn't something called "linked layers" available in GIMP?

Comment: @NotStandingwithGoGotaHome - no, it isn't.

Comment: @BillyKerr ok, then