# GIMP command to insert an image in a PSD file

Tags: gimp, layers

Having this [PSD file](https://ufile.io/3l5s9jzm) with a layer named "YOUR DESIGN | 5 x 7", what would be the GIMP command (in Linux) to insert a picture there and produce the final graphic file (JPEG, PNG) that includes it?

Comment: Does the PSD contain a smart object?  If so, then you can't use GIMP. It doesn't support smart objects in PSDs. It only has partial compatibility with basic PSD files, and it's not GIMP's native format anyway (which is XCF). PSD is a proprietory format owned by Adobe.  I very much doubt if the GIMP developers will ever implement full compatibility with PSDs, since there is every possibility Adobe could sue them. They've sued other software manufacturers before for copying their functionality.

Comment: There's a question I answered [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/119807/89608) which goes through one possible work around in GIMP.

Comment: Another possibility for creating mockups is Krita (also open source like GIMP), it has something similar to Smart Objects in its linked file layer functionality, although it doesn't actually support actual Photoshop smart objects.

Comment: @BillyKerr yes, the PSD file actually includes a smart object. In principle the target is just to insert the other image in this layer with GIMP, avoiding all the smart part. But may be Krita can make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally there's no hope without a program which can handle Photoshop's smart objects. Many programs, GIMP is one of them, can use the most basic layers of Photoshop, but their abilities get short when one should work with smart objects, adjustment layers etc... Photoshop's specialities which together are the backbone of templates and product mockups.

There's a couple of exceptions. Online program Photopea can interpret incredibly many features which as late as 2 years ago were inaccessible for those who couldn't use Photoshop. So, try at first Photopea!

The other exception is Affinity Photo. It can import Photoshop's adjustment layers and layer styles (no guarantee how exactly), but smart filters are rendered to flat pixel layers.

GIMP can open some simple enough PSDs which also may have smart objects. But no warps nor other effects incorporated to smart objects will work. Looks like your PSD is such simple case. The smart object only skews and clips the artwork to the frame in the base image. The lights and shadows of the base image are applied to the artwork via the blending mode of the artwork layer. The artwork is on the top, so there's also a layer mask. See the next attempt in GIMP:

[image]

I pasted a random news photo (a mortar man) as a new layer to your opened PSD. I copied the layer mask from the original artwork layer and skewed the image a little to make it as tilted as the frame is. That step is actually not needed. It's necessary only if the inserted image has long straight lines which must be aligned with the frame edges.

Photoshop and probably also Photopea would apply the pre-adjusted skewing of the smart filter automatically, but GIM doesn't do it. Fortunately the layer mask works perfectly.

The layer mask keeps the mortar man inside the frame and behind the chair and the plant. GIMP doesn't have the right layer blending mode, but mode Multiply seems to work well. I lifted the brightness of the mortar man a little because multiply darkens.

The layer mask was copied by converting it to a selection and the layer mask to my new layer was inserted by using the active selection as the layer mask.

Comment: Worth noting that Photopea, although it does support smart objects does not have the batch image editing capabilities of Photoshop, and since the OP is specifically asking for commands to do this (I assume command line in Linux), I'm not sure how useful Photopea would be for this specific use case, or even if manually doing this in GIMP is actually a feasible alternative.

Comment: The questioner also wanted to proceed only one image - he wrote "it", not "them". Maybe he can stand the graphic interface during one image.

Comment: @oneprivate the point would be to reproduce this process with a Scheme script, so it can be done (opening PSD file, inserting image, and saving) in a batch mode.

Comment: @nightcod3r Ok, insert it to the question. Of, course it makes this answer useless, but some advanced users might get interested - I mean people who do not bother to write about elementaries.

Comment: @oneprivate - it's already in the question, as I told you. The OP is looking for a command to do batch editing.

Comment: @BillyKerr my crystal ball is dusty. But maybe others can see better and one of them writes an actual answer.